# How do I display the copyright symbol in an XPage?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages

This seems like it should be simple.  Using the escape sequence of `&copy;` doesn't work when I enter this as text.  The XPages engine keeps escaping the ampersand character, causing the string to be written as a literal.

Answer (score 6):

XPages is XML and it doesn't know the HTML escape characters, hence the "escaping" of the `&copy;` symbol. I stumble over the same problem when designing XSLT stylesheets that output HTML.
What should work is: `&#169;`. Are you planting the code in the source of the XPage or do you compute it? If you compute it, make sure you pick the "HTML" option (escaped=false), not plain text.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Worked!  I figured it was something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you use the copyright symbol directly? © (Unicode code point U+00A9.)

[Wikipedia has several other options that may also work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_symbol).

Answer (score 2):

You can turn escaping off on a xp:text

```
<xp:text escape="false">
   <xp:this.value><![CDATA[&copy]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```