# How to display a TM character in xpages?

Tags: xpages

How can I display a tm character in xPages?  I would prefer it inside a label (with other text) but outside the label would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go to this page
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

copy the tm sign (it's at the bottom of the page) and past it into the label text.

Answer (score 2):

do you mean *©* ?

```
&#169;
```

Or *™* ?

```
&#8482;
```

Comment: The tm.  I was able to use your TM with Fredrik's answer above.  Thanks guys.  Shocking it is that simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer can help you in the right direction: [How do I display the copyright symbol in an XPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694587/how-do-i-display-the-copyright-symbol-in-an-xpage)

Trademark (tm) is 8482 so `&#8482;` should work.